# Ajax request results in "CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing"

Tags: ajax, apache, cors

I'm working on my local machine using WAMP and I'm trying to retrieve an image from an external domain using AJAX to convert it into data-uri format with the following code :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "https://domain.local/image.jpeg", true);
xhr.responseType = "blob";

xhr.onlaod = function (){

   // convert...

};
```

But I have an error that says "CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing".

I have already enabled "headers_module" in WAMP Apache modules and set `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in my httpd.conf file but I still have the same issue.

I tried to set `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` both in "httpd.conf" and ".htaccess". I tried to specifically allow the domain that sends the request. I also restarted WAMP a dozen times.

Is there anything else to do or the problem is elsewhere?